# In java, is an interface providing parameters to extend a parameterized interface an exact synonym of it?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I would like to use an interface as a short-name for a parameterized interface, so as to avoid polluting all the code with generic syntax. For example:

```
EggChicken egg = chicken.lay();  // Can't make it compile.
```

instead of:

```
Egg<AnimalChicken> egg = chicken.lay(); // Compiles happily.
```

Say I would like to model the animals reproduction modes Using parameterized classes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_of_reproduction). I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface Animal<T> {
   T lay();
}

interface Viviparous<T extends Viviparous> extends Animal<T> {
}

interface Egg<T extends Oviparous> {
    T hatch();
}

interface Oviparous<T extends Oviparous> extends Animal<Egg<T>> {
}
```

The idea being that viviparous animals *lay* new instances of the same animal, whereas oviparous animals *lay* eggs that *hatch* new instances of the same animal.

Now, I would like to define more precise interfaces to describe a Dog and a Chicken:

```
interface AnimalDog extends Viviparous<AnimalDog> {
}

interface AnimalChicken extends Oviparous<AnimalChicken> {
}

interface EggChicken extends Egg<AnimalChicken> {
}
```

Finally, those are the implementations:

```
public class AnimalDogImpl implements AnimalDog {
    @Override
    public AnimalDog lay() {
        return new AnimalDogImpl();
    }
}

class AnimalChickenImpl implements AnimalChicken {
    @Override
    public EggChickenImpl lay() {
        return new EggChickenImpl();
    }
}

public class EggChickenImpl implements EggChicken {
    @Override
    public AnimalChicken hatch() {
        return new AnimalChickenImpl();
    }
}
```

My problem comes when I want to use the the classes in code:

```
public class AnimalTest {
    @Test
    public void can_do_something_nice() {
        AnimalChicken chicken = new AnimalChickenImpl();
        // Error here:
        EggChicken egg = chicken.lay();
        AnimalChicken chick = egg.hatch();
       Assertions.assertThat(chick).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

I get the error: *Required EggChicken, found Egg<AnimalChicken>*, but this is precisely how I defined `EggChicken`. Is it possible to solve this kind of indirection?

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: `interface AnimalChicken extends Oviparous<AnimalChicken> {EggChicken lay();}`

Comment: There is a question of inherit hierarchy, A chicken can lay an egg, an egg can hatch chicken, but a dog should lay(bear) a dog directly, how comes to hatch behavior.

Comment: @caisil - Dog doesn't come to hatch behavior, because it extends ``Viviparous``, that allows to lay directly a Dog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a *type alias*.

Java unfortunately does not have them.

When you create a new interface, that defines a new type. An instance of `EggChicken` is also an instance of `Egg<Chicken>`, but not the other way around. You would have to make your `AnimalChicken` (interface!) return an `EggChicken` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The overall idea is correct, but there are problems in the hierarchy. An `Animal` can't lay a type that is either `Egg` or `Animal` directly, they're not related.
I think the following represents what you intended:

```java
    interface LayProduct {}

    interface Animal<E extends LayProduct> extends LayProduct{
        E lay();
    }

    interface Egg<E extends Egg<E,A>, A extends Oviparous<E,A>> extends LayProduct {
        A hatch();
    }

    interface Viviparous<A extends Viviparous<A>> extends Animal<A> {    }

    interface Oviparous<E extends Egg<E,A>, A extends Oviparous<E,A>> extends Animal<E> {    }


    interface AnimalDog extends Viviparous<AnimalDog> {
    }

    interface AnimalChicken extends Oviparous<EggChicken,AnimalChicken> {
    }

    interface EggChicken extends Egg<EggChicken,AnimalChicken> {
    }
```